# python dynamic checkbox request form

Tags: python, forms, checkbox

Hi i have created an input dynamic check-box with this

```
 {% for row in servit %}
    <label title='{{row.Descrizione}}'>{{row.Nome}}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{row.Nome}}a">Attivo
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{row.Nome}}p">passivo
 {% endfor %}
```

and it works.
I want to call the form in python and i have tried to do this:

```
    for row in test:
        testa=row.Nome+"a"
        testfa=str(request.form["testa"])
```

but without result, how can i do what i need, how can i put a variable inside the request.form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have find the solution by myself

```
testfa =request.form.get(testa)
```